# Find and replace in an AS3 String

Tags: string, actionscript-3, replace, find

I want to find the "(*" string in another string and then replace it 
with the < and / one but the method replace() can not do it.
Sorry, but I can not write the string in the description together :D

Here is my code:

```js
//Call the method like..
trace(searchandreplace("(*Foo)"));

  private function searchandreplace(input:String):String{
    var pattern:RegExp = /(*/gi;
    return input.replace(pattern,"</");
  }

Trace: //What I get:..
"(*Foo)"

Trace: //What I want...
"</Foo>"
```

It would be nice if someone can fix my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mask "(" and "*" in your pattern:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /\(\*/gi;
```